Looping in rxswift
hey i wanted to loop in rxswift, so my code flow first is fetching list of data id with this code
func fetchAllGamesWithPagination(_ page: Int) -> Observable<[ListGame]> {
        let url = URLBASE + "/games"
        let parameters = [
            "key": API_KEY,
            "page_size": "10",
            "page": String(page)
        ]
        
        return Observable<[ListGame]>.create { observer in
            AF.request(url, parameters: parameters)
                .responseDecodable(of: GameModel.self) { respons in
                    switch respons.result {
                    case .success(let result):
                        observer.onNext(result.results ?? [])
                        observer.onCompleted()
                    case .failure(let err):
                        observer.onError(err)
                    }
                }
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }

in ListGame theres id, after getting list game i used that id to get detail id with
 func fetchGameDetails(_ id: Int) -> Observable<GameDetailModel> {
        let url = URLBASE + "/games/\(id)"
        let parameters = [
            "key": API_KEY
        ]
        
        return Observable<GameDetailModel>.create { observer in
            AF.request(url, parameters: parameters)
                .responseDecodable(of: GameDetailModel.self) { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let detail):
                        observer.onNext(detail)
                        observer.onCompleted()
                    case .failure(let err):
                        observer.onError(err)
                    }
                }
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }

is it possible using rxswift for fetching ListGame first and then looping for getting entire data detail?

You can use flatMap and zip to acheive your goal:
func fetchData()  -> Observable<[GameDetailModel]> {
    fetchAllGamesWithPagination(0)
        .flatMap { list in
            Observable.zip(list.map {
                self.fetchGameDetails($0.id)
            })
        }
}


First let's clean up your code to get rid of the duplication. This also makes it easier to test that the correct data is being sent to the request without having to mock out the request:
struct Endpoint<Response> {
    let url: String
    let parameters: [String: String]
}

extension Endpoint where Response == [ListGame] {
    static func allGames(onPage page: Int) -> Endpoint {
        Endpoint(url: URLBASE + "/games", parameters: [
            "key": API_KEY,
            "page_size": "10",
            "page": String(page),
        ])
    }
}

extension Endpoint where Response == GameDetailModel {
    static func gameDetail(withId id: ListGame.ID) -> Endpoint {
        Endpoint(url: URLBASE + "/games/\(id)", parameters: ["key": API_KEY])
    }
}

func fetch<T>(_ endpoint: Endpoint<T>) -> Observable<T> {
    Observable.create { observer in
        AF.request(endpoint.url, parameters: endpoint.parameters)
            .responseDecodable(of: T.self) { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let success):
                    observer.onNext(success)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                case .failure(let failure):
                    observer.onError(failure)
                }
            }
        return Disposables.create() // this should be using the request's cancellation method.
    }
}

Now, if @duckSern1108's answer didn't get it for you, maybe you want both the ListGame, and its associated GameDetailModel together. To do that we can just add another zip:
func gamesWithData(page: Int) -> Observable<[(ListGame, GameDetailModel)]> {
    // we start with an `Observable<[ListGame]>`
    fetch(.allGames(onPage: page))
        // then map it to an `Observable<[Observable<(ListGame, GameDetailModel)>]>`
        .map { games in
            games.map { game in
                Observable.zip(
                    Observable.just(game),
                    fetch(.gameDetail(withId: game.id))
                )
            }
        }
        // then flatten out the extra Observable.
        .flatMap(Observable.zip)
}

You could make the above more concise if you want to. I spread it out a bit to fit the SO screen better and help show the steps.
